# Adequação de tela não está fazendo sua função "@media screen and() { }"

Tags: html, css

A adequação de tela não está respondendo os atributos definidos, aparentemente parece está certo, porém a largura e altura do objeto quando a tela do browser é reduzida em `(max-width:400px)` não surte efeito algum, uma coisa tão simples e não consegui resolver, o que pode estar dando errado??

```css
*{ padding:0px; margin:;}
.bl{ background-color:#F33; 
border:2px solid #000; 
margin:150px auto; 
position:relative; 
width:600px; 
height:300px;
}
@media screen and(max-width:400px){
 .bl{ width:200px; height:200px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="bl"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara seu problema é com isso `and(` a palavra não pode ficar colada no `(`

Tem que ser assim com espaço

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px)
```